# MYSQL join + replace?

Tags: mysql, join, replace

need help building a query to replace fields on a table that match a second table.

table1

```
city
```

table2

```
city | code
```

I need replace all occurrences of city on table1 by code of the table2 matching the city field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, not necessary for a replace:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.city = table2.city SET table1.code = table2.code
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it'll be something like this:

> update table1 t1 set t1.city = t2.code from table2 t2 where t1.city =
>   t2.city